# Is there any way to implement a JE instance for [a]?

Tags: pointers, haskell, judy-array

I'm writing a network processing program, and having some troubles. I decided to implement my directed graph as a [Judy Array](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/judy-0.4.1/docs/Data-Judy.html#t:JE) of linked lists of arcs. That is

```
JudyL [Arc]
```

where,

```
type Id  = Int
type Day = Int

data Arc = Arc { aid  :: Id,
                 time :: Day} deriving (Eq, Show)
```

However, Judy arrays require that their inputs can be converted to a Word value, or a word-sized pointer. In particular I must implement,

```
instance JE [a] where
     toWord :: [a] -> IO Word
     fromWord :: Word -> IO [a]
```

I however, have no idea whatsoever how to deal with pointers in Haskell. Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps I should just be using an array instead, but I fear that my dataset is very large (a terabyte uncompressed, though a lot of that data is extraneous) and have convinced myself that additional reads/writes on the (admittedly solid state) drive could seriously slow this down. IDK though.

Comment: What is JP instance?

Comment: You're totally right, I screwed up, meant JE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just copy and paste [the `ByteString` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/judy-0.4.1/docs/src/Data.Judy.html#line-848), which essentially allocates a new `StablePtr` and then casts it to `Word`. Keep in mind that you will need to do your own deallocation when (if) the time comes for that.